# How to send a .gif file over a serial port connection using C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I would like to send a .gif file over a serial port connection using C in Linux.

I know how to send bytes over the connection and receive them on the other hand, but have no real idea how to do it with a .gif file.

How can I send the image byte per byte over the connection and reconstruct it on the other end?

Thanks.

Comment: What is on the other end of the serial cable?

Comment: @Pekka: another computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a gif is no different than sending any other sequence of bytes.  As long as you're not using a file mode that tries to translate carriage returns and/or line feeds like some non-binary connections do, you just read the file in and send the contents, and on the other end read them off the connection and write them to a file.

Comment: thanks. I already thought that, but seeing someone with so much rep saying that reassured me, and I have now successfully sent the file over the serial port connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the Zmodem protocol. As a bonus, there is a description and source code at this site:  http://pauillac.inria.fr/~doligez/zmodem/